# Having problems running SQL script in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

The script is:

```
ALTER TABLE DBR_STATUS ADD IS_READY NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0;
COMMENT ON COLUMN DBR_STATUS.IS_READY IS 'Is engine ready?';
```

I get a `Syntax error` trying to run that. No details. That's just a small tooltip. What am I missing?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `Syntax error` Nothing really helpful...

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **complete** error message you get.  [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is an SQL developer syntax highlighting error - not an Oracle error (and the code still executes). It is going to difficult to show without a screen shot in this case.

Comment: @MT0: the title says "*problems **running** a script*". If a script that has been run generates an error it **will** have a complete Oracle error message. If there is no such message, then it's not a problem _running_ the script.

Comment: parenthesis probably, see  [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001)    EX:  alter table FOO add (BAR number)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've tried it - the code executes in an SQL Fiddle, in SQL Developer and in SQL/Plus - the only issue is that SQL Developer highlights a syntax error. On my copy of SQL Developer that does not prevent the code from executing - I do not know if there are preferences you can set that would prevent it from executing code it thinks has errors but I cannot replicate the "problems running" but I can replicate the "thinks it has syntax errors".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[TL;DR]** It appears to be a bug in SQL Developer's syntax highlighting and does not prevent code execution. Just ignore it.

---

Running the code:

```
CREATE TABLE DBR_STATUS ( ID INT );
ALTER TABLE DBR_STATUS ADD IS_READY NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0;
COMMENT ON COLUMN DBR_STATUS.IS_READY IS 'Is engine ready?';
SELECT * FROM DBR_STATUS;
```

You get a little red squiggly underline following the end of the comment (in this case on the first keyword of the next statement):

[image: Syntax Error]

If I run the code, it executes without issues:

```
Table DBR_STATUS created.
Table DBR_STATUS altered.
Comment on column dbr_status.is_ready 'IS ENGINE READY?' succeeded.
no rows selected
```

It appears to be a bug in SQL Developer and is something that you can just ignore.

Answer (score 2):

Please, always include the VERSION of SQL Developer you are having issues with.

I agree with @MTO's answer.

To add additional info, this does not present itself in the current version of SQL Developer, which is version 18.1.

```
create table dbr_status (
 a   integer
                        );

alter table dbr_status add is_ready number(1,0) default 0;

comment on column dbr_status.is_ready is
 'Is engine ready?';

select *
  from dbr_status;
```

And no problems indicated by the parser, as it should be.

[image]

Please update your question with version number if you are NOT on v18. Otherwise, the answer is you can: A)Safely ignore it. B)Upgrade.